# How do I place the Clock arrows inside this clock face?

Tags: graphics, dynamic

I am trying to program a clock, I have the face I want and the hands but I can not seem to put them together so they work.....

```
Dynamic@Module[{hour, min, sec, hourhand, minutehand, secondhand}, 
  Clock[]; {hour, min, sec} = Take[DateList[], -3]; (* 
  The Dynamic Time *)
  
  hourhand = Pi/2 - 2 Pi hour/12 - 2 Pi min/720; 
  minutehand = Pi/2 - 2 Pi min/60;
  secondhand = Pi/2 - 2 Pi Floor[sec]/60; (* 
  The Clock Hands Position *)
  
  
  
  clock = 
   Graphics[{Thickness[0.013], Style[Circle[], Blue], 
     Thickness[0.003], Point[{0, 0}], (* 
     Circular Rim and center Point*)
     
     Table[
      Line[{0.9 {Cos[a], Sin[a]}, 0.95 {Cos[a], Sin[a]}}], {a, 0, 
       2 Pi, 2 Pi/60}], Thickness[0.018],(* Little Ticks *)
     
     Table[
      Line[{0.9 {Cos[a], Sin[a]}, 0.95 {Cos[a], Sin[a]}}], {a, 0, 
       2 Pi, 2 Pi/12}],(* Big Ticks *)
     
     Table[
      Rotate[Style[
        Text[IntegerString[i, "Roman"], 
         1.1 {Cos[-i Pi/6 + Pi/2], Sin[-i Pi/6 + Pi/2]}], Bold, Thick,
         35, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], i*-30 Degree], {i, 1, 
       12}]}]](* Roman Numeral's *)


[Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.1], 
  Arrow[{{0, 0}, 0.5 {Cos[hourhand], Sin[hourhand]}}], 
  Arrow[{{0, 0}, 0.70 {Cos[minutehand], Sin[minutehand]}}], 
  Line[{{0, 0}, 0.85 {Cos[secondhand], Sin[secondhand]}}], 
  PointSize[Medium], Point[{0, 0}], 
  Circle[]}]](* Graphics for the clock Hands *)
```

The output is:

[image]

However it does not display the hands... Separately both pieces of code work correctly.

Part 1 The clock face:

```
    clock = Graphics[{Thickness[0.013], Style[Circle[], Blue], 
   Thickness[0.003], Point[{0, 0}], (* 
   Circular Rim and center Point*)
   
   Table[Line[{0.9 {Cos[a], Sin[a]}, 0.95 {Cos[a], Sin[a]}}], {a, 0, 
     2 Pi, 2 Pi/60}], Thickness[0.018],(* Little Ticks *)
   
   Table[Line[{0.9 {Cos[a], Sin[a]}, 0.95 {Cos[a], Sin[a]}}], {a, 0, 
     2 Pi, 2 Pi/12}],(* Big Ticks *)
   
   Table[Rotate[
     Style[Text[IntegerString[i, "Roman"], 
       1.1 {Cos[-i Pi/6 + Pi/2], Sin[-i Pi/6 + Pi/2]}], Bold, Thick, 
      35, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], i*-30 Degree], {i, 1, 
     12}]}](* Roman Numeral's *)
```

Output:
The same as above.

Part 2 The analog time:

```
  Dynamic@Module[{hour, min, sec, hourhand, minutehand, secondhand}, 
  Clock[]; {hour, min, sec} = Take[DateList[], -3];
  
  hourhand = Pi/2 - 2 Pi hour/12 - 2 Pi min/720; 
  minutehand = Pi/2 - 2 Pi min/60;
  secondhand = Pi/2 - 2 Pi Floor[sec]/60;
  Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.1], 
    Arrow[{{0, 0}, 0.5 {Cos[hourhand], Sin[hourhand]}}], 
    Arrow[{{0, 0}, 0.70 {Cos[minutehand], Sin[minutehand]}}], 
    Line[{{0, 0}, 0.85 {Cos[secondhand], Sin[secondhand]}}], 
    PointSize[Medium], Circle[]}]]
```

Output:

[image]

And the arms move with the correct system time. However I can not get them to work together.....

Comment: The first example in the "Neat Examples" section of the documentation for [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) is to "Display an analog clock with current system time"

Answer (score 7):

You have to combine the clock face and clock hands graphics. I am using `Show` since that changes your code the least:

```
Dynamic@Module[{hour, min, sec, hourhand, minutehand, secondhand, 
   grClock, grHands},
  Clock[];
  {hour, min, sec} = Take[DateList[], -3];(*The Dynamic Time*)
  hourhand = Pi/2 - 2 Pi hour/12 - 2 Pi min/720;
  minutehand = Pi/2 - 2 Pi min/60;
  secondhand = Pi/2 - 2 Pi Floor[sec]/60;(*The Clock Hands Position*)
  grClock = 
   Graphics[{Thickness[0.013], Style[Circle[], Blue], 
     Thickness[0.003], Point[{0, 0}],(*Circular Rim and center Point*)
     Table[Line[{0.9 {Cos[a], Sin[a]}, 0.95 {Cos[a], Sin[a]}}], {a, 0,
        2 Pi, 2 Pi/60}], Thickness[0.018],(*Little Ticks*)
     Table[Line[{0.9 {Cos[a], Sin[a]}, 0.95 {Cos[a], Sin[a]}}], {a, 0,
        2 Pi, 2 Pi/12}],(*Big Ticks*)
     Table[Rotate[
       Style[Text[IntegerString[i, "Roman"], 
         1.1 {Cos[-i Pi/6 + Pi/2], Sin[-i Pi/6 + Pi/2]}], Bold, Thick,
         35, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], i*-30 Degree], {i, 1, 
       12}]}];
  
  grHands = 
   Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.1], 
     Arrow[{{0, 0}, 0.5 {Cos[hourhand], Sin[hourhand]}}], 
     Arrow[{{0, 0}, 0.70 {Cos[minutehand], Sin[minutehand]}}], 
     Line[{{0, 0}, 0.85 {Cos[secondhand], Sin[secondhand]}}], 
     PointSize[Medium], Circle[]}];
  Show[{grClock, grHands}]
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: Sir thank you so much! I have been struggling with this for hours. I did not even now about "Show".

Comment: Ok, good luck! We can also use `Graphics[{grClock[[1]], grHands[[1]]}]` instead of `Show[{grClock, grHands}]`.

Comment: OK, good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the built-in [`ClockGauge`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClockGauge.html):

```
Dynamic @ Refresh[ClockGauge[Round@AbsoluteTime[], 
  Charting`LabelSide -> Left, 
  GaugeFrameSize -> None, ImageSize -> Large, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 35], ScaleOrigin -> .75, 
  "TickLength" -> {20, 15}, 
  LabelingFunction -> (Pane[#3, ImageMargins -> 15] &), 
  TickLabels -> RotateRight[IntegerString[Range@12, "Roman"]], 
  TicksStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Butt"], Black], 
  GaugeStyle -> Black, 
  Epilog -> {Directive[Blue, AbsoluteThickness[5]], 
    Circle[{0, 0}, .8]}], UpdateInterval -> 1]
```

[image]

Could not find a convenient way to rotate and align tick labels using `LabelingFunction`. Below, I construct the labels separately as as an `Arrow` with custom `Arrowheads` and add it as `Epilog`:

```
arrowheads = {.1, #/12, Graphics[{Text[Style[IntegerString[#, "Roman"], 35, Bold], 
  {0, 0}, {0, -1}, N@{Cos[-Pi/12], Sin[-Pi/12]}]}]} & /@ Range[12];

hourminutesecondhands = {Graphics[{Thick, Black, Arrowheads[Large], 
     Arrow[{{0, 0}, {3, 0}}]}], 
   Graphics[{Thick, Black, Arrowheads[Large], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {3/2, 0}}]}], 
   Graphics[{Thin, Black, Line[{{0, 0}, {3/2, 0}}]}]};

Dynamic @ Refresh[ClockGauge[Round @ AbsoluteTime[], 
   GaugeFaceStyle -> None, 
   GaugeFrameSize -> None, 
   "TickLength" -> {20, 15}, 
   LabelStyle -> None, TicksStyle -> Black, 
   GaugeMarkers -> hourminutesecondhands, 
   Epilog -> {AbsoluteThickness[10], Blue, Circle[{0, 0}, .98],
     Black, "LineOpacity" -> 0, Arrowheads[arrowheads],
     Arrow[Prepend[Reverse@#, First@#] & @ CirclePoints[{1, Pi/2}, 12]], 
     Disk[{0, 0}, .03]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-3/2, 3/2}, {-3/2, 3/2}}, ImageSize -> Large], 
  UpdateInterval -> 1]
```

[image]